# Saints of the last two centuries whose existence is in doubt

Tags: religion

[image: St. Peter]

Saint Peter the Aleut, or Chukagnak, was supposed to have been a man from Kodiak forced to labor for the Russian-American Company and brought to California. According to his colleague Kyglaia, in 1815, Chukagnak was tortured to death by a Spanish mission priest because he refused to become a Catholic. He is venerated as a saint by at least some parts of the Eastern Orthodox Church. The story has been endlessly disputed.

Are there more recent saints (i.e. since 1815) of established religions whose very existence is in doubt?

Comment: By 'more recent' do you mean since 1815? And by "whose historicity is in doubt" are you referring to doubt about their existence or doubt about their qualifications for sainthood? If the latter, I'd suggest that every recent saint is an example.

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, and the former -- nothing about the historicity of miracles.

Comment: Russian = Orthodox saints, or any kind of saint?

Comment: @Jos: "...of established religions."

Comment: Mother Theresa and Pope John Paul II (not a saint .... yet) come to mind. Both are very dubious, to say the least.

Comment: @Jos : even if their contributions to the world (judged by Catholic values) are debattable, I don't think the **existence** of Mother Theresa or Pope John Paul II are much in doubt.

Comment: @Evargalo - I should hope not. I still have about 3 Pope John Paul II slurpee cups left over from his trip to NOLA in the 80's. It'd be a shame to have to ditch them to preserve the timeline.

Comment: Re "established religions", AFAIK only one religion has the notion of saint, and only some sects of that religion accept the continuous creation of saints in recent historical times.

Comment: @T.E.D. If peoples historicity is determined b slurpee cups, I'm going to have a field day once I've found a manufacturer ;)

Comment: @jamesqf: Sufi Islam and Hinduism, to name but a couple, also possess similar concepts.

Comment: There is the case of the [Martyrs of Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrs_of_Natal); the "unknown number" of people "hacked to death" on "3 October 1645" the number of _saints_ re the event has been set at "30 individuals" due to "Not even the names of all have come to us: for this reason, the ecclesiastical authorities have reduced the list to only 30 characters, in initiating their cause of beatification". While the individuals' "very existence" is not in "doubt", we do not have their exact names, 7 of which are described as "7 lay companions of Martins" ("João Martins – layman").

Comment: @orangesandlemons - does my "Babe" mug count? :'(

Comment: "The story has been endlessly disputed." By who? The Spaniards, I presume?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Sure, and I think also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Pierce_(historian)

Comment: IIRC the Catholic Church has pretty strict metrics for canonization.  3 witnessed miracles or the like.  In the last 20 years or so, it got officially downgraded to 2 to smooth things over.  And I really really struggle to think any that John Paul II pulled off.  The Devil's Advocate, that's where the expression comes from, really hasn't been doing his job questioning whether or not something qualifies as unexplainable by mundane means, i.e. a miracle.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher That's miracles through intercession of the (future) saint (after their death and beatification), not anything they had done during their lifetime.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher People become saints in a different way in the orthodox church. Because its not centralized, it just sort of happens. There are a few ways it happens, and martyrdom is one of the ways. Anyhow, this question isn't about that, but about whether this person is real or not.

Comment: With the modern canonization process, I pretty much doubt that there are modern saints whose existence is in doubt in the Catholic. Maybe the exact number of people may be dubious as in the Brazilian example above. Church. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatification_and_canonization_process_in_1914

Comment: A modern example where a group of people was canonized: the Uganda Martyrs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uganda_Martyrs) Suppose that the list in some case like this is not 100% reliable. Besides that, in a group canonization, sometimes the formula "Saint X and his companions" is used when the full name list is not known. But I do not know modern examples.

Comment: @Luiz As stated above, people become saints in the orthodox church in a manner different from the Roman Catholic church. This question, if you read it closely, is about a person the Roman Catholic church tortured to death because he refused to give up Orthodoxy.

Comment: @Relaxed I was more commenting on Jos' point than on the question of existence or not.  And John Paul II got canonized suspiciously soon after his death, so it's not an exactly trust-inspiring exercise there.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher Sure, and I certainly did not intend to advocate any particular position in this respect. I am just pointing out that whether John Paul II “pulled off” any miracle himself simply isn't relevant.